# can video/audio or other multimedia streaming work without an SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, video-streaming, lms

I have an app which I have uploaded on the web now It is an E-learning application which requires video/audio or other multimedia streaming features e.g. It will have video chat and virtual classroom feature.

Now the thing is that I have heard from, someone, that If I don't have an SSL certificate on my website I won't be able to stream data online such as voice calls, virtual classroom, audio streams, etc.

Comment: Generally: no, you do not need an SSL certificate to stream audio/video. Specifically: *maybe yes*. If your site is served via SSL, then everything on it will require SSL as well. If you're using WebRTC/web sockets, you may be required to use SSL. You'd need to be more specific about how exactly you want to serve your audio/video. In general: in this day and age you should always be using SSL by default, oftentimes it's available for free with your hosting in some way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes you should get an SSL certificate to live stream videos, audios, etc using WebRTC especially if your user uses Google Chrome then he won't be able to experience the full functionality of your product as google cares a lot about security.

Comment: Thanks for your answer yes you are right I have also looked up some sites after you answered and they also say the same thing as your answer.